# How to create a progress bar while downloading a file from server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

How to create a **progress bar** while downloading a file from server in iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Following code for the download progress bar display

## import "UIDownloadBar.h"

```
@interface yourClassViewCtr : UIViewController <uidownloadbardelegate ,UIAlertViewDelegate> {
    UIDownloadBar *bar;
    UILabel *lblForDisplay;
    UIAlertView *alert;
}
```

Delegate method code

```
#pragma mark - UIDownloadBar Delegate Methods

- (void)downloadBar:(UIDownloadBar *)downloadBar didFinishWithData:(NSData *)fileData suggestedFilename:(NSString *)filename {
//  NSLog(@"%@", filename);
//    NSLog(@"%@",fileData);
    
    UIImage *img=[UIImage imageWithData:fileData];
    UIImageView *imgVctr=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 25, 200, 100)];
    imgVctr.image=img;
    
    //store locally data into the resource folder. 
    [self.view addSubview:imgVctr];
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}

- (void)downloadBar:(UIDownloadBar *)downloadBar didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}

- (void)downloadBarUpdated:(UIDownloadBar *)downloadBar {
}
```

[For more detail visit following tutorial.](http://goo.gl/1Ap8B)

This may helping to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use [download helper class](https://github.com/erica/iOS-5-Cookbook/tree/master/C15/03-Download%20Helper) to download a file and it shows progress bar indication too..

Answer (score 0):

You should not have the progress bar in the main thread of your UI.

Best approach is to create another thread and put your progress bar there. You may send this thread some update information like the percentage so it updates in the speed you like.

Once you are done downloading the thread can be killed - or leave it for subsequent downloads in the background.

Comment: How would you safely put view on a background thread like that? Why shouldn't you update it in the main thread?

Comment: ...because the app might get blocked if there is a problem with the download - then the UI just freezes - this is not the best user experience. But as for this purpose - as Prince pointed out - might be the more direct approach. Anyway, Apple/Android etc strongly recommend not to place such code in the main UI thread due to the explained UI blocking issues. It's quite straight forward to create a new thread for this - just search for http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/83317/BackgroundWorker-and-ProgressBar-demo

Comment: Your answer reads like you are saying to update the UI element itself from a background thread which could turn out badly. Not that you are saying to run the connection on a background thread. You should of course do that, but signal to the main thread to update the progress bar as data comes in. I don't think that came across in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
if (self) {

    [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:0.8]];
    [self setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];

    self.downloadMessage=[[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, frame.size.width-80, frame.size.height/2)] autorelease];

    [self.downloadMessage setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
    [self.downloadMessage setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:11]];
    [self.downloadMessage setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
    [self.downloadMessage setText:@"Downloading Assets..."];
    [self.downloadMessage setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self addSubview:self.downloadMessage];
    [self.downloadMessage setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

    float offset=(frame.size.width-200)/2;
    self.progressiveView=[[[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault] autorelease];

    [self.progressiveView setFrame:CGRectMake(offset, frame.size.height/2, 200, frame.size.height/2)];
    [self.progressiveView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];
    [self addSubview:self.progressiveView];
}
return self;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response{

expectedLength+=response.expectedContentLength;
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{  

@try{

int index=[self.urlConnections indexOfObject:connection];
progressValue+=((float)((float)data.length/(float)expectedLength))*0.9;
[self.progressiveView setProgress:progressValue];
[[self.preCacheDatas objectAtIndex:index] appendData:data];
}
@catch (NSException *exception){
}
}
```